# Implemented L-BFGS from TensorFlow Probability, But how to store loss values in every epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

Implemented L-BFGS from TensorFlow Probability with Tf2 neural network model, referring to the method in this article https://pychao.com/2019/11/02/optimize-tensorflow-keras-models-with-l-bfgs-from-tensorflow-probability/
But while trying to store the loss values in each epoch it is throwing an error. But L-BFGS optimization is working fine but I was not able to get the loss value.

code snippet for generating the function which is given to value_and_gradients_function of L-BFGS
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTWjk.png)

line 118, in f  *
tf.py_function(f.loss.append, inp=[loss], Tout=[])

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'loss'
```

Please see the above code snippet: Thank you for your response in advance
This is my first time asking a question in StackOverflow please let me know if there are any mistakes.

Comment: This is my first time asking a question in StackOverflow, if I have made any mistake please let me know